# Controllability of LTI Networks

Tags: dynamical-systems, control-theory, linear-control

Let us assume a 4-node network, described by $\dot x = A x + B u $, where

$$ A=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ b & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\ c & 0 & 0 & e \\\ d & 0 & 0 & 0
    \end{pmatrix}. $$

What is the intuitive difference from an engineering point of view between choosing the input to be a matrix

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
    b_1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\\
    0 & b_2 & 0 & 0 \\\
    0 & 0 & b_3 & 0 \\\
    0 & 0 & 0 & b_4
    \end{pmatrix}
$$
and the input to be a vector
$$ B=\begin{pmatrix}
    b_1  \\\
    b_2  \\\
    b_3  \\\
    b_4
    \end{pmatrix}?
$$

Comment: Your first choice of $B$ implies that $u$ has 4 components, while your second choice of $B$ implies that $u$ is a scalar. Those are very different situations. Do you have an independent control on each component of the dynamic (first choice)? or do all the components share the same one control (second choice)? Also the form for $A$ you provided seems irrelevant.

Comment: This is what I am interested in understanding. You said that in the first choice, we have an independent control on each component while in the second one, all the components share the same control. Does this have to do with the time I am applying control? 
For example, in the first case, am I applying consecutive stimulations to the components one after the other, while in the second case I am applying stimulations simultaneously?

Comment: No, in both cases you are simulating all the states simultaneously. For example, you could use Euler's method to update the state as $\ x(t+\Delta t) = x(t) + \big{(}Ax(t) + Bu(t)\big{)}\Delta t$. You cannot decouple the simulations component-wise because there are off-diagonal terms in your $A$ matrix.

Answer (score 0):

As @jnez71 proposed the first $\boldsymbol{B}$ does give you more control authority, because your input vector $\boldsymbol{u}=[u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4]^T$ has four components instead of a scalar component $u$ for the vector $\boldsymbol{b}$. Because of this, you have a higher degree of freedom for the control of your system.

In order to see this, we can look at a simplified system

$$\dot{x}_1=x_1 + u_1$$
$$\dot{x}_2=x_2 - u_2$$

we can quickly see that $u_1=-x_1-k_1x_1$ and $u_2=x_2+k_2x_2$ will drive the system to the origin if $k_1$ and $k_2$ are positive.

If we look at the same system but with only one input we will have

$$\dot{x}_1=x_1 + u$$
$$\dot{x}_2=x_2 - u.$$

If we apply $u=-x_1-k_1x_1$, we can stabilize the first equation for $k_1>0$. The problem is now that the second equation will now be directly affected by this choice of $u$.

$$\dot{x}_2=x_2+x_1+k_1x_1$$

Hence, we cannot freely choose $u$ without constraining the values of $k_1$ which will lead to an asymptotic behavior of the system. It turns out that for this example we will not be able to stabilize the system with such a control law.

I hope you can see how we lost control authority by having a vector instead of a matrix as the input matrix.